# How should I set up a relational database with multiple post types?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

I'm working on a database for a news site, and am not sure what the best practice is to split up the tables. It will have four different categories, each containing different fields:

News

- Headline
- Subhead
- Date
- Story content
- Optional photo

Webinar

- Date
- Time
- Link

Event

- Name
- Date
- Time
- Location
- Description
- Link

Contest

- Start date
- Name
- Description

Should I make:

- a single table for all of them
- a different table for each category type
- or a table with all of the common fields, and separate tables for each category's unique values?

Answer (score 2):

There is no one "right" answer. It depends on several factors.

(Fortunately, you didn't mention implementing an Entity Attribute Value (EAV) model. I strongly recommend you avoid that.)

Some factors to consider:

Consider relationships... will each "category" have the same relationships to other entities? You show "event" having an attribute of `location`... is that an attribute, or does that represent a relationship to another entity?

Consider how your queries will need to be written. Will you frequently need to query rows from several of the "category" together? For a large number of rows, for best performance, you'll want to avoid inline views tat use `UNION ALL` to combine separate tables into a single view.

There is lots of good information available about mapping an "inheritance hierarchy" into a relational database, the pros and cons of each approach, and examples of what that looks like, and (most importantly) what the queries look like.

**FOLLOWUP**

If the requirement is to handle each category separately, and you don't need to query the combined category, then I would go with a separate table for each category (Option 2), for ease and simplicity.

If you need to query the combined category (e.g. select from all category `ORDER BY date_col`, then I would probably go with a single table, with a discriminator column (`category`) to be able to distinguish which category a row is. Based on the limited number of attributes, I'd be tempted to define all the attributes, and then just populate the ones that apply to each category. (Option 1)

The third option is workable too. All three options can be made to work.

Comment: It will be pretty straightforward, I don't think any of the attributes will have a relationship to other entities. The main page will list the paginated posts, only displaying the title, date, category and description, with a link to the full article. There will also be a dropdown menu where you can select to only view them from a certain category.

Thanks for the advice about not using `UNION ALL`. I'm a total noob so it's good to know these things (also had no idea there was a term for inheritance hierarchy)...my educated guess would be to use my third suggestion. Does that sound right?

Comment: Also when you click through to a specific post it will list other posts in that category, if that makes any difference